# raspberry full noobs installation from network

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am looking for a way to install noobs raspbian from network. I mean i do not want to connect an hdmi TV, mouse or keyboard.

What i read in documentation is to download noobs (full version) and copy files into sd card. I have read i need to change something in recovery.cmdline file (Adding vncinstall word).

This works for the first raspberry boot: I can see installation screen through VNC. I have choose "Raspbian + pixel" installation. Then, I can see the progress bar.

But at the end of the installation, when the raspberry reboots, i have no VNC, neither ssh or telnet server and at this time i need to plug an HDMI TV, mouse and keyboard.

Do you know how i can automaticly launch a VNC or SSH server without having to plug a TV and keyboard ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `raspi-config` to enable or disable ssh. After this you should be able to connect

Comment: Yes but i need a TV and a keyboard to run raspi-config

Comment: Okay. You cant.